# poudriere Error: no such pool: tank

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to create a poudriere jail (fresh FreeBSD 11.1 Host System) on a ZFS file system. But when I try to initialze the jail with

```
root@host:/ poudriere jail -c -j 11amd64 -v 11.1-RELEASE
```

I get

```
====>> Error: No such zpool: tank
exit: parallel_shutdown: not found
```

I expected the pool to be be create by poudriere. Do I have to create the pool manually?

Comment: In case want to create an instance with zfs on root give a try to http://fabrik.red/ you can download the image or create your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  you need a `zfs pool`, in the case that you already have one, check that your `zpool` name is "tank", you can do this by typing:

```
$ zpool list
```

Output should be similar to

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank   896G  14.1G   882G         -     2%     1%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Notice the `NAME` column, in this case,  indicates that there is a pool named `tank`

Probably you have `zroot` instead of `tank` just double check what is the name of the pool(s) you have and add it to your configuration. This is what I am using in `/usr/local/etc/poudriere.conf`

```
ZPOOL=tank
ZROOTFS=/poudriere
FREEBSD_HOST=https://download.FreeBSD.org
RESOLV_CONF=/etc/resolv.conf
BASEFS=/usr/local/poudriere
POUDRIERE_DATA=${BASEFS}/data
USE_PORTLINT=no
USE_TMPFS=yes
DISTFILES_CACHE=/usr/ports/distfiles
CHECK_CHANGED_OPTIONS=verbose
CHECK_CHANGED_DEPS=yes
PKG_REPO_SIGNING_KEY=/usr/local/etc/ssl/keys/pkg.key
CCACHE_DIR=/var/cache/ccache
NOLINUX=yes
URL_BASE=http://your-url
```

It is also possible to use poudriere with no ZFS:

```
# For NO ZFS:
NO_ZFS=yes
```

You can find more about it here: https://github.com/freebsd/poudriere/wiki/pkg_repos

Comment: Thank you so much! I only that would have been explained in the FreeBSD poudriere documentation too.